# On the mobile phone, is there a "mac address" that makes each mobile phone different?

Tags: mobile, unique, uniqueidentifier, mac-address

In other words, is there an ID for each and every mobile phone--that makes it different.

No two phones can have the same ID. (I'm talking about smartphones ...android, iphone, etc)

Comment: +1 I think this was the 500,000th question. congrats.

Answer (score 4):

Phones have MAC addresses on WiFi interfaces, but the cellular interface has something called an [IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity), that performs roughly the same function.

Comment: Finding your MAC address on a Google Android-based phone http://it.usu.edu/htm/faq/faq_q=3979

Find the iPhone MAC address
http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/05/find-iphone-mac-address/

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the IMEI is linked to the physical device/phone, as opposed to the IMSI which is linked to the SIM card and therefore the customer account. Not sure how you'd go about getting hold of either from within an app running on the phone, assuming that's what you're doing.